# regular expression to fetch the specific pattern

Tags: python, regex, filter

I need to fetch the specific rule from the filter list that how many rules are there in with this category.

I have tried to fetch this type of rule from the filter list. The rule pattern is as follows

> " /example.com $script,domain=example.com "

and the second exception rule is

> "@@/example.com $script,domain=example.com "

third rule with domain anchor is

> "||example.com

whereas fourth rule with anchor and domain tag is

> "||jizz.best^$popup,domain=vivo.sx

and the fifth one is

> "@@||pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js$script,domain=quebeccoupongratuit.com

6th one with domain restriction is as follows

> "example.com###examplebanner

7th without domain restriction is

> "###examplebanner

8th is exeptional with element hidding

> example.com#@##examplebanner

These are  different categories of rules I have to fetch separately

```
a=open('1-19-16anti-adblock-killer-filters.txt','r')
text=a.read()
 line_starts_with_2pipes_no_domain = 0
  line_starts_with_2pipes_with_domain = 0
 line_starts_with_2ats_with_domain = 0
 line_with_domain = 0

 for line in text.split("\n"): 
   if line.startswith("||"):
    if ",domain" in line: 
        line_starts_with_2pipes_with_domain += 1
    else:
        line_starts_with_2pipes_no_domain += 1
  elif line.startswith("@@") and ",domain" in line:
    line_starts_with_2ats_with_domain += 1
   elif ",domain" in line: 
    line_with_domain += 1
   elif line.strip(): 
      print(f"No idea what to do with :{line}")

print("2pipes_no_group", line_starts_with_2pipes_no_domain ) 
print("2pipes_with_group", line_starts_with_2pipes_with_domain ) 
 print("2@_with_group", line_starts_with_2ats_with_domain ) 
 print("line_with_domain", line_with_domain)
```

i am trying now to fetch 5th , 6th ,7th and 8th rule . Your response will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: kindly guide me regarding this @blhsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not fit the `,` before domain:

```
"\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+domain="
#                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ no , allowed
```

You can also simplify this a lot:

```
with open("easylist.txt") as f: 
    print('There are total Rule With Domain tag are =', f.read().count(",domain="))
```

should give you your answer of how often `',domain='` occures. If your file is big, you can also count linewise:

```
domain_rule_count = 0
with open("easylist.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        domain_rule_count += 1 if ",domain=" in line else 0
```

---

Edit after question in comment:
You simply test for what you want:

```
text = """ some text
/example.com $script,domain=example.com
@@/example.com $script,domain=example.com 
||example.com
||jizz.best^$popup,domain=vivo.sx
"""

line_starts_with_2pipes_no_domain = 0
line_starts_with_2pipes_with_domain = 0
line_starts_with_2ats_with_domain = 0
line_with_domain = 0

for line in text.split("\n"): 
    if line.startswith("||"):
        if ",domain" in line: 
            line_starts_with_2pipes_with_domain += 1
        else:
            line_starts_with_2pipes_no_domain += 1
    elif line.startswith("@@") and ",domain" in line:
        line_starts_with_2ats_with_domain += 1
    elif ",domain" in line: 
        line_with_domain += 1
    elif line.strip(): 
        print(f"No idea what to do with '{line}'")

print("2pipes_no_group", line_starts_with_2pipes_no_domain ) 
print("2pipes_with_group", line_starts_with_2pipes_with_domain ) 
print("2@_with_group", line_starts_with_2ats_with_domain ) 
print("line_with_domain", line_with_domain)
```

Output:

```
No idea what to do with ' some text'
2pipes_no_group 1
2pipes_with_group 1
2@_with_group 1
line_with_domain 1
```

Comment: i am trying to count rule catagory wise like some rule are with domain anchor "||" and domain tag "domain=" where as some rule are with only domain tag "domain=" like in the above example and some are with only domain anchor so i am divinding these rule in three types  1. ||example.com  2. @@||shoqolate.com^$script,domain=games.pch.com and 3. ||padsdel.com^$domain=oload.tv|openload.co|streamango.com 4. /example.com $script,domain=example.com        so what patteren will be for these type of rule ?  i'll be thakful to you if make it for me @Patrick

Comment: @kash If you want to exclude some lines - test for what you want to exclude:  `domain_rule_count += 1 if (",domain=" in line and not line.startswith("||") ) else 0` ... your description does not make much sense to me - maybe add more example data by [edit]ing your question. Comments are notoriously bad for formatting text.

Comment: i have updated the question . kindly update your code for the last time because new rule are added here and i am facing problem particularly with 5th and 8th . I m trying to fetch rule with only domain tag like "  /example.com $script,domain=example.com "    "
@@/example.com $script,domain=example.com   "but it also count @@||pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js$script,domain=quebeccoupongratuit.com

Comment: @kash Kindly take my code as guideline and adapt your new rules yourself. Thanks.

Comment: i m trying from that time but unable to do it. i have made this pattern for the 5th one is" elif line.startswith("@@")or ("/") and ",domain" and not "@@||"  in line:     
        line_starts_with_2ats_with_domain += 1    " but it count @@|| this rule also

Comment: made for the fifth one only if possible , Anyhow you have helped a lot @patrick